# How do you hide users from Login and Fast User Switching under OS X 10.7 Lion?

Tags: macos, login

Historically, it was possible to hide users from the login screen.  In pre-10.5 times, one simply changed a userid to < 500 and:

> sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow Hide500Users -bool YES

Since ~10.5, the sequence is:

> sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow HiddenUserList -array-add
>
> sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED -bool false

However, I am unable to get my admin account to hide from the window in 10.7 using FileVault 2.  Has anyone else had a similar experience and does anyone know how to make this work properly?

Comment: I did `# defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow HiddenUsersList -array-add hUser` when I was on Snow Leopard, then upgraded to Lion and the `hUser` account is still being hidden (caveat: I have `SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED -bool true` i.e. I still have "Other…" in the login screen). Where Lion fails, exactly? Is it the `SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED` or FileVault 2—or something else?

Answer (score 3):

This change didn't get implemented/respected/carried forward in Lion 10.7 initial release build. It's an open bug with no ETA on a fix or resolution.